# What do the colors mean in htop?

Tags: colors, htop

[image: htop screenshot]

For the CPU cores, I think that blue means nice, green normal CPU use and red I/O.
But I'm not sure and I haven't found a definite answer.

Then there are the colors for memory. What do green, blue and yellow mean there?

Comment: I lack the reputation credits to flag this as duplicate, but **see the answer at http://serverfault.com/questions/180711/what-exactly-do-the-colors-in-htop-status-bars-mean**, which is a copy of your question and has been answered.

Comment: @CalebXu You cannot flag it as a duplicate of a question on another site, but you can post an actual answer here, linking to it.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Press <kbd>h</kbd> inside htop for quick help.

**CPU**

```
Blue      : Low-priority threads
Green     : Normal priority threads
Red       : Kernel threads
Turquoise : Virtualization threads
```

**Memory**

```
Green         : Used memory
Blue          : Buffers
Yellow/Orange : Cache
```

Comment: [For anyone wondering what's meant with *cache*](http://askubuntu.com/a/155771/132098)

Comment: Why is the kernel CPU on the right? Wouldn't it make sense to put it on the left?

Comment: @AaronFranke, because your processes are expected to primarily use User CPU. Kernel CPU is when your process calls a kernel function which should use a lot less time in %.

Answer (score 52):

Also, in the list of processes, there are some that appear in Green. The black ones are main processes and the Green ones are threads. In my example below, I'm running a repair on a Cassandra node and as we can see most entries are threads.

[image]